# Ticks To Date Time Converter in xamarin form write a converter

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, converters

In This below response LogDate is Ticks Formate and i want conver
into DateTime Formate Make sure my datetime fiels is string .How can i write Converter in xamarin form to conver ticks to date time

"id": 1508559,
"frequency": null,
"logDate": 1616762243000,
"freq": null,
"freqCompare": null,
"weekOfYear": null,
"userName": "1008042:GB4GICKtSOxitObxcaP9Nw",
"documentWords": 72,
"documentLength": 437,
"sessionId": "PDBD6371FDF4249579502E47096995131",
"docCorrections": 0,
"foundString": "Xamarin",
"serverString": "Xamarin",
"userString": "",

Comment: Does that solve your problem?

Comment: No ,Stil i am Strugling ,

Comment: Did you already deserialize the response from the API using Newtonsoft.Json?